# Modifying/overriding a library class' methods properly

Tags: android, websocket, java-websocket

I'm using WebSocket Rails-Android library by ararog.

I subscribe to a few channels in a loop based on data I receive from the server-side. I'm using the same WebSocketRailsDataCallback for all channels and the only varying thing is the channel name. My problem is that the callback's `onDataAvailable(Object data)` data contains only the received JSON, which doesn't contain the channel name, and I failed to find a way to know on which channel the response was received.

I tried to create custom interface and class that extends WebSocketRailsDataCallback and WebSocketRailsChannel respectively with `onDataAvailable(Object data, String channelName)` signature and overriden `dispatch` method, but the class' variables are private, which means that I cannot have a constructor like the following and thus can't cast the WebSocketRailsChannel to the custom class:

```
public CustomWebSocketRailsChannel(WebSocketRailsChannel channel)
    {
        super(/*channel arguments*/);
    }
```

I can get the fields using `getDeclaredFields()` in methods, but it doesn't help me with casting (which I need because `dispatcher.subscribe` method returns the base class).
The next solution I thought about was creating full custom classes for all the relevant classes (dispatcher, channel, dataCallback, etc.) instead of inheriting it, but it's a rough solution. Another one is contacting and library author. Any better and simpler idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved; I went too deep without noticing that I can do it by overriding the DataCallback only. I created the following class:

```
public abstract class CustomWebSocketRailsDataCallback implements WebSocketRailsDataCallback {
    public CustomWebSocketRailsDataCallback(String channel)
    {
        mChannel = channel;
    }

    public String mChannel = null;
}
```

Created an instance of this class, saved the channel name in mChannel and accessed it in onDataAvailable.